# Changing a simple database class in order to support prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

My question is about my code.
I have created 2 websites. But it's on mysqli PHP OOP. Someone told me that these queries are SQL Injection. So, i wanna change my database structure to prepare statements. Then, i can save my websites from SQL Injection. For that, I need your help.
**Here is my database structure:**
**config.php**

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "lunch");
?>
```

**Database.php**

```
<?php
    $filepath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    include_once ($filepath.'/../config/config.php');
?>
<?php

Class Database {

    public $host = DB_HOST;
    public $user = DB_USER;
    public $pass = DB_PASS;
    public $dbname = DB_NAME;
    public $link;
    public $error;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connectDB();
    }

    private function connectDB() {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
        if (!$this->link) {
            $this->error = "Connection fail" . $this->link->connect_error;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function select($query) {
        $result = $this->link->query($query) or
                die($this->link->error . __LINE__);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function insert($query) {
        $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or
                die($this->link->error . __LINE__);
        if ($insert_row) {
            return $insert_row;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update($query) {
        $update_row = $this->link->query($query) or
                die($this->link->error . __LINE__);
        if ($update_row) {
            return $update_row;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function delete($query) {
        $delete_row = $this->link->query($query) or
                die($this->link->error . __LINE__);
        if ($delete_row) {
            return $delete_row;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

**And i am writing my queries like this:**

```
<?php
    $filepath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    include_once ($filepath.'/../lib/Database.php');
?>

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['name']);
$query = "INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('$name')";
$result = $this->db->insert($query);
if($result != false){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$result = $this->db->select($query);
$value = $result->fetch_assoc();
$name = $value['name'];

$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = '$dlt_user'";
$result = $this->db->delete($query);
if($result){
    header("location: rd-user.php");
}

$query = "UPDATE users SET name = '$name' WHERE user_id = '$userid'";
$result = $this->db->update($query);
if ($result){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

**Hey Your_Common_Sense brother! See this screenshot:**
[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MflOv.png)
So, kindly please check my database structure and queries and tell me how can i change my db structure to prepare statements and how can i prevent from SQL Injections. **Please help me.**

Comment: BTW that's not your database structure, please visit that link, that is very useful

Comment: It's not created by my own, but my meant was that i am using this

Comment: btw, which link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find different methods in your class quite redundant. they all do the same thing, while differ only in the name. So first of all let's remove all but one method. I would also remove some other cargo cult code from the class as well.

Then you will need to rewrite your [connection code](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect) in order to add the **error reporting** and the **character set support**. Add `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` to your config file as well.

Then you have to rewrite the only method left in this class in order to add the support of prepared statements. Refer to my article, [Mysqli helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) for the details.

```
Class Database {

    public $link;

    public function __construct() {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        try {
            $this->link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        mysqli_set_charset($this->link, DB_CHARSET);
        } catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = [], $types = "")
    {
        if ($params) {
            $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
            $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->get_result();
        } else {
            return $this->link->query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use your class with any kind of query utilizing prepared statements

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES(?)";
$this->db->query($query, [$data['name']]);
header("Location: index.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
$result = $this->db->query($query, [$user_id]);
$value = $result->fetch_assoc();
$name = $value['name'];

$this->db->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?",[$dlt_user]);
header("location: rd-user.php");

$query = "UPDATE users SET name = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
$this->db->query($query,[$name,$userid]);
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: Can we use mysqli_real_escape_string() in this? to create variable like this: `$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['name']);` or if we use prepare statements then we  need to use simply like this: `$name = $data['name'];` ?

Comment: Brother, your code giving me a lot of errors. Please check the screenshot I've updated my question with screenshot of errors.

Comment: Zain, copying the code without understanding how it works is a recipe for disaster. In this case YCS made only a small typo, which would be easily fixable if you tried to understand the code. Just replace all occurrences of `$mysqli` with `$this->link`

Comment: worked, but what about if i am not using `WHERE` condition in `SELECT` query,  coz query($sql $param) requires 2 parameters, but if i want all data except `WHERE` then we don't need $params in query(), what i can do then?